# Immunity Debugger PyPlugin

Tags: python, immunity-debugger

[Immunity Debugger](http://www.immunityinc.com/products-immdbg.shtml) offers a feature called **PyPlugin**. However there is not enough documentation on it. The help for immdbg says this :

> PyPlugins are python scripts located at PyPlugins\ directory,
>   PyPlugins are called when F4 or the PyPlugin icon located at the main
>   toolbar are pressed. Both (F4 or the PyPlugin icon) will popup a file
>   browse dialog, where the starting folder is the PyPlugin Directory.
>   When a pyplugin is executed, its main() gets called. Please note a
>   pyplugin can not receive any arguments and will not return any value
>   other than inscreen errors.

In reality when the <kbd>F4</kbd> key is pressed, nothing special happens. <kbd>F4</kbd> is actually the shortcut to *Run to selection*. Further there is no *PyPlugin* icon located at the main toolbar. The *PyPlugins* directory under Immunity Debugger directory is also empty, so no examples to look.

My question is what is a *PyPlugin* ? Are there any ready made *PyPlugins* to refer as an example ?

<sub>**Note** : I am only talking about **PyPlugins**, not **PyCommands**</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going over

- [ImmunityDbg presentation](https://github.com/kbandla/ImmunityDebugger/blob/master/docs/dc-15-gomez.pdf) - page 26,
- [v1.73 dir](https://github.com/kbandla/ImmunityDebugger/tree/master/1.73) - dir structure
- [ImmDbg help file](https://github.com/kbandla/ImmunityDebugger/blob/master/1.73/Documentation/IMMLIB.HLP) - "PyHooks ... they look exactly as a python plugin, only that they are placed inside PyHooks directory."

I'm making and educated guess that `PyPlugins` is probably a leftover from previous versions of the debugger and at some point it became known as `PyScripts`.

So, the actual examples and guidance could be found [here](https://github.com/kbandla/ImmunityDebugger/tree/master/1.73/PyScripts)

Comment: Looks reasonable enough. Perhaps they are artifacts from older versions.